# Why is second scanf being skipped over?

Tags: go

I decided to take a look at Go and I am currently stuck on something.  In this program, I am asking the user to choose option 1 or 2.  If option 1 is chosen, I want the ReadAppList function to ask the user for a last name.

It seems as if the second scanf is being skipped over and not allowing the user to enter a last name.  Is it only reading the first user input?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


// Main function that runs on startup
func main() {

    fmt.Println("\n1. Search Last Name ")
    fmt.Println("\n2. Exit ")
    fmt.Println("\nPick an option: ")
    var userAnswer int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &userAnswer)

    if userAnswer == 1 {

        ReadAppsList()

    } else if userAnswer == 2 {

        fmt.Println("\nGoodbye.")

    } else {

        fmt.Println("\nThat is not a valid choice.")

    }
}

func ReadAppsList() {

    fmt.Println("\nType your LastName of the person you want to look up: ")
    var lastName string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &lastName)
    fmt.Sprintf("You typed %s", lastName)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because extra newline not being consumed by first scanf.
Change your scanf to this `fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &userAnswer)`.

Comment: This is unnecessary on my machine. Maybe it's an OS difference?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn, it seems this is happening on windows.

Comment: @KadeWilliams so it should fix your issue.

Comment: That worked.  I searched Google for a while and didn't see anything on that.

Comment: Just tested it. My Linux Mint x64 laptop doesn't need the `\n`, my Windows 10 x64 desktop does need the `\n`. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

In your ReadAppsList you have:

```
fmt.Sprintf("You typed %s", lastName)
```

The problem is that `Sprintf` returns a string without writing to the screen. Change that to `Printf` and it'll print the lastname.

The `Scanf` for the last name is happening as you'd expect.

Comment: It is still doing the same thing.  It does not allow a user to enter a name, before and after the change.  Once you type 1, it runs through to the end of the program.